# Adding width to parent layout by button release using Kivy language

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a simple problem to which I cannot seem to find a straight answer. I am trying to, on a click of a child button, increase the parent layout width by a specific increment.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
GridLayout:
    width: 200
    size_hint_x: None
    cols:1
    Button:
        size_hint:1, 0.07
        text:"Add"
        on_release: root.parent.width + 100
    Button:
        size_hint:1, 0.07
        text:"Remove"
        on_release: root.parent.width - 100
```

In this simple example by pressing the `Add` button should add `100` width to the parent grid layout and visa versa with the `Remove` button. However, not sure how to call the change of width with `on_release: root.parent.width`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to `root.parent` you are referring to whatever is containing the `GridLayout` that appears in your `kv`. If you want to adjust the size of the `GridLayout`, just use `root.width`. Also, using the `+` operator does not change the value, it just adds to value and returns the result. Try changing your `kv` to:

```
GridLayout:
    width: 200
    size_hint_x: None
    cols:1
    Button:
        size_hint:1, 0.07
        text:"Add"
        on_release: root.width += 100
    Button:
        size_hint:1, 0.07
        text:"Remove"
        on_release: root.width -= 100
```